# Fee on transfer tokens and uniswap V2

Tags: uniswap

I am implementing a uniswap v2 front end interface for a UniswapV2Router contract. I was wondering how does uniswap identifies when swapExactETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens needs to be used instead of swapExactETHForTokens. In other words, how does the uniswap interface identifies fee on transfer tokens? Also for both these functions does the user only need approve the router ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your two questions:

1. How does uniswap identifies when swapExactETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens needs to be used instead of swapExactETHForTokens.

- As their name, if the swapped token have the function of, for example, take 10% fee when transfering token. Thus, you have to use swapExactETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens. For the Frontend code of Uniswap you can refer to their sdk at https://github.com/Uniswap/v2-sdk. In their code, they also define logic of using these two functions as (https://github.com/Uniswap/v2-sdk/blob/81948482505b09da3282c7bcd93945eef1992f71/src/router.ts#L114)

```
const useFeeOnTransfer = Boolean(options.feeOnTransfer)

const methodName = useFeeOnTransfer ? 'swapExactETHForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens' : 'swapExactETHForTokens'
```

2. Both these functions does the user only need approve the router ?

- The answer is No if you swap from native token to standard token, eg. swapExactETH... However, if you swap from standard token to native token (i.e., WETH to LDO), you have to approve the router to use the token.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thank you! do you think there would a problem just always using SwapSupportingFeeOnTransfer tokens by default for all tokens even those that do not have fees ? This would make it more simple to implement instead of having to handle all cases.

Comment: Great question. For my perspective, I guess using two separate functions allow Uniswap to improve precision and user intent. Because, mixing different functionalities in a single function might lead to confusion for users and also increase the complexity of the code (uniswap code is complex already).  And, also, using two separate functions can improve clarity and readability for developers. They can quickly understand the intended functionality of each function based on its name, and thus, make it easier to choose the appropriate function based on their specific requirements.